# Lambda function making an athena query and the query result is not in the S3 output bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I'm querying an S3 bucket with athena through python boto3. The query is successful and there are no errors but the output S3 bucket is empty. But when I run the query through the python console it works and there is .csv and .csv.metadata with the athena query results in the S3 output bucket.

I have added permissions mentioned on this page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html

Not sure if this matters but the S3 output bucket where the query results should be is not managed by serverless (that's what I'm using for my project) it is an existing S3 bucket and I used this package and instructions https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-existing-s3 and it works fine with dynamoDB and glue Catalog information getting dumped when a lambda is trigered.

```
def function(event,context):
client = boto3('athena')
query = 'select * from athenaTable'
response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=params["query"],
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': params['database']
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://bucket-name/key/' #output bucket
        }
    )
    return response
```

Comment: When you say "when I run the query through the python console it works", do you mean the Athena console? What are the permissions on the credentials being used to call `start_query_execution()`? Do those credentials have `PutObject` permissions on the target bucket?

Comment: I mean on the python shell. It's able to read the permissions correctly from my shell environment. Yes it has the PutObject permissions. I'm using aws serverless for all setting up all the iam roles with the lambdas

Comment: I suspect it might be a issue related with this package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-existing-s3. So, I'm going to try and make the target bucket a serverless created S3 bucket and see if it works

Comment: It sounds like the credentials being used to run the code do not have sufficient permissions, whereas when you run it locally you are using a different set of credentials that _do_ have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue I was able to solve it by changing the permissions to my lambda function. So make sure the Role for your lambda has the correct policies.

I solved it by giving full access to `Athena` and `Glue`. Add those policies to your lambda role.

Full access may be more than what you actually need, so just select the necessary policies from those services